# Java default methods with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, default-method

I am learning the Java 8 syntax and came across a piece of code in our application below in an interface:

```
default EmployeeEnricher employeeEnricher() {
      return builder -> {
          return;
      };
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what the above syntax means?

There are multiple implementations of this method in the application, each with its own logic.

Comment: It returns an instance of `EmployeeEnricher` which we can assume is a `FunctionalInterface` (can be represented as a lambda). It would seem this one is akin to a `Consumer<T>` where the T is whatever that builder variable is. Lambda don't have to be passed to methods, they can be assigned to variables or just outright declared, as they are a value (not a statement themselves).

Comment: Like with ordinary methods, such an explicit `return;` is not necessary, so `builder -> {}` would do, which would emphasize that this `EmployeeEnricher` simply does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just returns an `EmployeeEnricher` which basically is a `Consumer<Builder>` (or a functional interface from the same kind) which does nothing with its parameter meaning that if the class implementing the interface doesn't `@Override` this method, this will become its default behaviour (meaning nothing will happen).

In your application, you'll encounter different types of employees probably which will be enriched in different manners using a builder given in parameter using `employeeEnricher().accept(builder)`

This means implementation can mean two things for me :

- Either the design is poor, and all employees should have their own implementation, meaning this interface's method should not have be  `default` but simply a classic `abstract` method of the interface
- Either some employees do not get enriched in the context of your application, and thus this method offers a default implementation making sense

Comment: We don't know that `EmployeeEnricher` is a `Consumer<Builder>` - it can be any functional interface, not necessarily derived from `Consumer`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You're right, I'm adding the explanation